# Ajax call not being made in jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this jQuery code that runs on form submit:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function()
{
    $("input[type=submit]").click(function()
    {
        var name = $("#problem_name").val();
        var problem_blurb = $("#problem_blurb").val();

        var dataString = 'problem_name='+ name + '&problem_blurb=' + problem_blurb;

        if(name=='' || problem_blurb == '')
        {
            $('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
            $('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
        }
        else
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "problems/add_problem.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function()
                {
                    $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
                    $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
                }
            });
        }

        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

And in the directory named /problems/ I have a php file add_problem.php and that file simply has this so I can see in the logs that it is being called:

```
<?php
echo ".......in problem";
?>
```

But this never gets written to the logs.  Is there something wrong with my ajax call? I know that the js gets to the ajax part fine because I had some alert statements there that I took out.

Comment: Have you debugged this with firebug?

Comment: Actually I use Chromes JS console, but it doesnt show any problems there.

Comment: Looks alright as far as I can see.  Have you tried using Firebug or a similar developer console? This will let you see more information on the POST you're making, and wether or not your script is actually hitting add_problem.php.  Also, you can make an error function just after success, and look for log statements there.

Comment: And the ajax call isn't there in the network tab?

Comment: what do you mean by logs? I don't see what's the problem here. You are not doing anything with `.......in problem` try `success: function(data) { alert(data);...`

Comment: Oh yeah I was trying to get that "....in problem" to output to the logs so I know the request gets there.  I don't see if for some reason.

Comment: try input[type=button] and change the submit to a button

Comment: @mplungjan  didnt seem to work. If it helps to view the source and the page, it is here http://www.problemio.com

Comment: If the answer you accepted worked, your would have seen a 404 in your firebug

Comment: Also check your browser plugins, such as AdBlock. It might sound crazy, but they could silently prevent the AJAX request from being made if your URL has some pattern they recognize as unwanted. I just spent a couple of hours searching for a solution to a similar "ghost disconnect" problem. Everything worked perfectly after I modified my URL so it isn't picked up by AdBlock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file that contains this javascript is not located in the same directory that contains problems/ you should change:

```
 url: "problems/add_problem.php",
```

to

```
 url: "/problems/add_problem.php",
```

Comment: That actually worked although I had it the way you recommend some time ago, and it didn't work then. Weird.  :) Thanks anyway!!

Comment: Just wrestled with a related issue myself last night (it's at the top of my list of questions).